# Collection filter date range not working

Tags: magento2, collection, date

I tried to find the collection that has a range created between 4 hours, but somehow it doesnt show the right collection size, it always returns '0', here's how i use the filter:

```
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time() - (3600*4)); //4 hour;
//$from = 2018-04-03 06:29:19;
//$to = 2018-04-03 10:29:19
$collections = $this->mymodel->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $from])
        ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $to]);
```

here's the data in database:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got entries created within 4 hour :

```
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-4 hour')); // past 4 hour;
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$collections = $this->mymodel->create()->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['gteq' => $from])
        ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', ['lteq' => $to]);
```

It works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
->addFieldToFilter(
            'created_at',
            array('from' => $from, 'to' => $to)
        )->load();
```

Comment: Please remove array () syntax. It's not coding standard for magento2